# delete subtree from bst and balance the tree in logn time

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

Is it possible that we could perform m insert and delete operations on a balanced binary search tree such that delete operation deletes a node and the whole subtree below it and after that balance it? The whole process being in done in amortized O(log n) time per step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it is possible.

What you are describing is a self balancing binary tree, like an AVL-tree or a Red-Black tree. Both take O(log n) for deletion, which includes reordering of the nodes. [Here](https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS241/notes/self%20balance%20bst.htm) is a link to a page describing such trees and how they work in much more detail than I can, including illustrations. You can also check out the [Wikipedia page of AVL-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), they have a decent explanation as well as animations of the insertions. Here is a short version of what you were most interested in:

Deletions in an AVL tree are on average O(log n) and the rebalancing is on average O(log n), worst case O(1). This is done by doing rotations, again, well explained in both the sources.

The Wikipedia page also includes some code there, if you need to implement it.

**EDIT:**

For removing a subtree, you will still be able to do the same thing. [Here](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/340/340notes/340avl2.htm) is a link to a very good explanation of this. Short version: deleting the subtree is can be done O(log n) (keep in mind that deletion, regardless of the number of nodes deleted is still O(log n) as long as you do not directly rebalance the tree), then the tree would rebalance itself using rotations. This can also change the root of your tree. Removing a whole subtree is of course going to create a bigger height difference than just the deletion of one node at the end of the tree. Still, using rotation the tree can be rebalanced itself by finding the first node imbalance and then doing the AVL rebalancing scheme. Due to the use of the rotations, this should still all be O(log n). [Here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Trees/AVL-delete.html) you will find how the tree rebalances itself after a deletion, which creates a height imbalance.

Comment: I m sry but it seems u didn't get my question.
I want to delete a subtree and not just one node and then re balance it
in an amortized O(logn) time per delete operation

Comment: It is all good. Still if you remove a subtree the tree will be able to rebalance itself using rotations. I will edit my answer to match your question better. Sorry for the confusion.